# How do show different angles of an object on multiple monitor screens?

Tags: camera

I am trying to create a project where the object is showing on 4 different monitor screens. The 4 angles being the front, the sides, and the back. While its giving the effect that it looks like the background/atmosphere is spinning around the object on each monitor screen, but the cameras focus is on either the front, sides or back only, per each monitor screen. Can someone help explain step by step what to do? Thank you

Comment: Under the menu called `View` at the top of the viewport, you can select `Area > Duplicate Into New Window` to make a new viewport window for each of your monitors. You can then use the ortho perspective keys (Numpad 1, 3, 7, 9) on each of the windows to get your different front/back/top/side views. Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you are looking for Quad View?
[image: description of quad view from the docs]